# Robolectric = Mockito : Cannot Create Mock or Spy In Mockito Because: dexcache == null

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have a well reported issue here:

[Mockito + Dexmaker on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267572/mockito-dexmaker-on-android)

However the solution does not work.

I am using Robolectric and even when I try setting the dexmaker cache location:

```
@Before
public void setUp()
{
    System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", RuntimeEnvironment.application.getCacheDir().getPath());
}
```

The error changes to

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.android.dx.DexMaker.generateClassLoader(DexMaker.java:366)
at com.android.dx.DexMaker.generateAndLoad(DexMaker.java:439)
at com.android.dx.stock.ProxyBuilder.buildProxyClass(ProxyBuilder.java:264)
at com.android.dx.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.createMock(DexmakerMockMaker.java:56)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
at org.mockito.Mockito.spy(Mockito.java:1368)
```

Do you have any ideas that will enable me to create Mock or Spy objects using Robolectric?

Note: When I don't use Robolectric and use a regular `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` I can create Mock and Spy objects...

This issue has arisen after Mockito 1.9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robolectric + Mockito](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970899/robolectric-mockito)

Comment: My problem is different and the solution is different.

Comment: Your solution is different because Mockito didn't support dexmaker prior to 1.9.5. If you ensure you don't use mockito-android, you can use any version you'd like.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman is `mockito-android` a specific SDK you are referring to? I don't have any dependency for that

Comment: It's a name I've seen used in Maven and Gradle for a Mockito package that includes dexmaker. If you can use Mockito in instrumentation tests, then you are including Dexmaker one way or another. Check your build rules, and consider updating your question to include it.

Comment: You don't need dexmaker for Robolectric. Robolectric is used with jvm plain junit tests, that are run on build machine and don't require dexiing

Comment: Also please remove robolectric-gradle plugin. It is outdated

Comment: In fact, I'm quite sure it's the mistaken inclusion of dexmaker that's the problem. (By "include it" I meant "include your build file in your question, if you need more help".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this workaround:

https://comadeblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/dexcachenull-for-mockito-on-robolectric/comment-page-1/

TL;DR:

Use `compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.0'`. Higher versions will throw this error.

This is the only way I have found to get it work with Robolectric.

Answer (score 1):

Robolectric is used for unit tests that are run on build machine JVM. You don't need **Dexmaker** for these tests.

So please correct your `build.gradle`:

```
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:${versions.dexmaker}"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:${versions.dexmaker}"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:${versions.dexmaker}"
```

Comment: It is true that I could safely remove those, but I still get the same error unless I use Mockito 1.9 or less.